# Blank footnotes when using chem-acs

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biblatex-chem

I'm new to LaTeX and writing a chemistry thesis.  I would like all of my references to be footnotes (i.e. no bibliography at the end), formatted in the ACS style.  To that end, I want to use `biblatex`, Biber, and the `chem-acs` style, as this seems to be the cleanest approach.

However, when I run the code below, the footnote just has a number, no text.  Interestingly, if I use a verbose citestyle with `chem-acs` bibstyle, I get aaaaalmost what I want...except it does et. al instead of all three authors.  There's got to be something embarrassingly simple I'm missing, but what?

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=chem-acs,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
Some text. \autocite{Buchwald}
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the reference info:

```
@article{Buchwald
,   title   = {A new palladium precatalyst allows for the fast Suzuki-Miyaura coupling reactions of unstable polyfluorophenyl and 2-heteroaryl boronic acids.}
,   author  = {Kinzel, Tom and Zhang, Yong and Buchwald, Stephen L}
,   journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.}
,   volume  = {132}
,   number  = {40}
,   year    = {2010}
,   pages   = {14073--14075}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observe, `chem-acs` doesn't (currently) have `\footcite` set up to provide what you want. You are on the right track thinking you can mix bibliography and citation styles, but you'll need to set `maxnames` manually

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Buchwald
,   title   = {A new palladium precatalyst allows for the fast Suzuki-Miyaura coupling reactions of unstable polyfluorophenyl and 2-heteroaryl boronic acids.}
,   author  = {Kinzel, Tom and Zhang, Yong and Buchwald, Stephen L}
,   journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.}
,   volume  = {132}
,   number  = {40}
,   year    = {2010}
,   pages   = {14073--14075}
}\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibstyle=chem-acs,citestyle=verbose,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Some text. \autocite{Buchwald}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll probably look at updating `\footcite` to address this.